# How to let homeless user operate unsafe repository

Tags: git

After version 2.35, git will fail when doing git operation if user is not the owner of git repository due to a patch for a CVE issue.

A quick **fix**(Well, I think it is just a temporarily method.) for users with home is setting git config.

```
git config --global --add safe.directory {git repo path}
```

However, this method cannot apply to a homeless user. Git config need to lay in user's home directory.

How to let homeless user operate unsafe repository (setting some environment variable)?

Comment: how could a user homeless while have access and accessing a server?

Comment: I don't know enough about this, but I wonder if you can apply the safe.directory to the system-wide git config (git config --system)?

Comment: @djdomi a process runner

Comment: @Zoredache but this operation affects every user.